# how can i force swagger cogen jar 3.0.41 to use okhttp3 instead okhttp?

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

I downloaded swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.41.jar and run it to generate java api client and it uses okhttp, which is outdated.

I want to force swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.41.jar, to use okhttp3 4.10.0 and not okhttp-2.7.5

is it possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you make the 'generate' call, you can set the library flag to 'okhttp4-gson' and it will use okhttp3.

Problem is, when it builds, it tries to use jcenter instead of something like mavenCentral.

I got around this by building a custom version of the swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.46.jar and editing the build.gradle.mustache file in the handlebars\Java\libraries\okhttp4-gson folder to use mavenCentral.
I also changed it, build.sbt.mustache, and pom.mustache to tweak the version to 4.11.0 and update the swagger annotations to v3.